# parsing of regular expression in to local vars using match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these assignments:

```
const [x, y] = line.match(/\d+,\d+/g, line)[0].split(',');
const [width, height] = line.match(/\d+x\d+/g, line)[0].split('x');
this.id = line.match(/^#\d+/g, line)[0].split('#')[1];
```

When parsing a line of text like this:

```
#1 @ 265,241: 16x26
```

Can anyone suggest a more succinct way of parsing this?

Comment: What do you expect to see as result?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's string `replace` member method allows you to replace a regex with a string.  Replace 1 or more of any character that isn't a digit, globally, with a space.  Then use the string `split` member method to parse the result on space, then assign those 5 tokens to `this.id`, `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`.

```
const [this.id, x, y, width, height] = line.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ' ').split(' ');
```